# ASM Builds for BoringSSL currently not supported on: linux-aarch64

Tags: python, linux, firebase, termux, arch

> I am trying to Install firebase-admin on Termux using this command :

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

> Python Version :

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.1
```

> Pip version :

```
$ pip -V
pip 20.3.1 from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

> Installation Fails with this error :

```
ASM Builds for BoringSSL currently not supported on: linux-aarch64
```

> Also , tried with `Python 2.7` still, facing the Same Issue. Any Workarounds ?

> Full StackTrace :

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-btbtn_ga/grpcio_154dc9427ab04d429a4c3b2c56c107fa/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-btbtn_ga/grpcio_154dc9427ab04d429a4c3b2c56c107fa/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-1tz_62k3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.9/grpcio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you happen to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully installed firebase-admin by downgrading setuptools and installing an older version of grpcio.

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall setuptools
$ sudo pip3 install setuptools==49.6.0
$ sudo pip3 install grpcio==1.31.0
$ sudo pip3 firebase-admin
```

tested on pico-pi-imx7d board running ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with Python 3.8.5 and pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8) installed.